# Selector is already specified earlier

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I just create a new page, delete everything change name, and still think is specified somewhere else.

[image]

I try

> FIND ALL REFERENCES  Ctrl + K, R

But dont understand what mean, just appear same code twice.

```
Find all "/* BEGIN EXTERNAL SOURCE */

        #layout-main-container {
            background: red;
        }

/* END EXTERNAL SOURCE */
/* BEGIN EXTERNAL SOURCE */

        #layout-main-container {
            background: red;
        }

/* END EXTERNAL SOURCE */", Match case, Whole word, Subfolders, 
  Find Results 1, Entire Solution, "*.css;*.less;*.scss;*.sass"
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 3
```

Comment: you need to restart visual studio!

Comment: @LucianBumb really? how offten this happen?

Comment: I don't know, I have 2-3 times per day strange behaviors and always after restart is running ok. Usually when I create a new ActionResult, is telling me to add return but I already have it.

Comment: @LucianBumb Thanks. But this is so dumb :@

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think this has got something to do with how the page is actually rendered. I use a layout page so I don't have `<head>` and `<body>` elements in my cshtml file, but my problem was solved by placing the `<style>` element at the end of the file within Styles section:

```
@section Styles {
  <style>
    #layout-main-container {
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must notice to google advise. [https://support.google.com/360suite/optimize/answer/6262084#step-2][1]

The page-hiding snippet should be placed immediately before the modified Analytics tracking code **(after the  declarations)**.

I did this notice and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late for this answer but I just recently ran into this issue. Upon creating a new page with no styles in the styles.css file, I was doing inline styles on the page for a quick mock up and I was getting this error.

After a small amount of research, found out it was related to Web Essentials that I have on my VS2015 install. There is an option to turn it off in the VS Options.

Tools -> Options -> Web Essentials -> CSS.

Under validation, set the Validate duplicate selectors to false.

Again, not sure why this isn't working properly but this is how I fixed it for the time being.